# How to make an interactive tree chart with d3?

Tags: charts, treeview, d3.js

Is there any sample of how one could design an interactive tree chart like in the pearltrees.com web site (see [here](http://www.pearltrees.com/#/N-s=1_465472&N-p=6845530&N-u=1_37150&N-fa=465472&N-f=1_465472) for example) with D3 ?

thanks for any help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a force-directed graph to do something like this:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20110921/#20

You would have a bit of work to do:

1. Add images dynamically to the nodes ([this example adds a favicon](http://bl.ocks.org/950642) to each node)
2. Allow users to expand/collapse parts of the tree. ([this example does this, but uses a tree layout](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html)).
3. Add HTML links to the end nodes ([this example shows how nodes can link out to other pages](http://bl.ocks.org/1625629)).

Comment: thanks for those links, you're rigth that need a lot of work to do -:)